# Cache_page table gets massive

Tags: 8, caching

My cache_page table fills up immensely. I see that the expiry field has values = -1. I assume that means it never expires. Which could be why the table fills up so much.

I wrote a hack to get around this, but would really like to know why this is happening so I can fix the root cause instead of adding a hack?

Comment: Impossible to solve from afar.

Comment: Any other info I can provide to make it easier to solve?

Comment: What is massive? Each unique URL will result in a cache entry in that table, that is by design. As @4k4 wrote, you can set a lower limit manually, but the only thing that does is that clear out all entries over the limit by age. Until you run cron, it will still grow over that limit. If you have a lot of content, then you want it to be big because you want your content to be cached. 404 pages should already be limited to 1h by default. The uniqueness also covers query arguments, so it could also be query arguments, for a search, pager or someone might send a lot of requests.

Comment: Another alternative is to use a cache backend like Redis or Memcache which have built-in limits and have more intelligent purging implementations (they can delete infrequently used entries and not just old ones)

Comment: It was gaining 100 Mb a day, and never becoming less... ever. So day 1, 100mb, day 2, 200 mb, day 3, 300 mb etc. And it would basically become terabytes in size if I didn't manually clear it every couple of days. I wrote a hack to do this for me, but ideally I'd like to know why it's not clearing in the first place.

Comment: Before D8.4 it would grow like this unlimited. Since then the core was patched and the grow is limited, so it will stop eventually and won't become terabytes in size. Probably 1 or 2 gigabytes dependending on the single page sizes. You can stop this earlier by looking how many rows you have in the page cache at a certain point and using this as a limit.

Comment: The default size since 8.4 is 5000, Drupal should frequently delete entries lower than that. How many entries are 100/200Mb? It doesn't really make sense that it grows consistently like that each day, I would expect that more and more pages are then being cached. So again, check the cid's, which is basically the path and see if you can detect any patterns.. e.g. a lot of searches or other query arguments from crawlers or so. Also make sure cron is running

Comment: Did you have cronjobs enabled? This was the problem I had. Just rerun cron and all the cache tables get purged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set a lower limit than the default 5000 for the number of cache items that are stored in the page cache bin:

*settings.php:*

```
$settings['database_cache_max_rows']['bins']['page'] = 500;
```

See this change record: [Database cache bins are now fixed size — no more unlimited growth](https://www.drupal.org/node/2891281)