# How do I make the cache smaller?

Tags: caching

After we deployed our website to production, the number of users is big, so the cache size is also too big (30 GB); I believe its created per user per page. Our website for now only contains public sections, so no need to cache it per user per page.

Is there an option or a configuration to enable caching per page only in order to reduce the total cache size?

Comment: Pages are normally not cached per user. Even if you have a block containing user data it doesn't affect the page because Drupal is configured to placeholder such blocks by default.

Comment: ok in that case, is it normal that cache size (30 GB)? is there a way to decrease it?

Comment: If user content is not the problem you can decrease the overall sizes of cache tables, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267106/cache-page-table-gets-massive/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cache\_page table gets massive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267106/cache-page-table-gets-massive)

Comment: i am using redis for cache store, does this setting $settings['database_cache_max_rows']['bins']['page'] = 500; word also for redis?

Comment: No, you don't need this for Redis. You should configure Redis as an LRU cache like Memcached. See https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache